# Gravity Forms - Don't Save Field Data on Databse

Tags: php, database, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

My client wants to collect personal information through email but not have that info saved on the database. I'm using the Wordpress Gravity Forms plugin. Is there a way to have that info sent out through the email notification like normal, but then clear out the data before saving the entry to the database? Or at the very least, could that data be replaced with alternate content? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, this is software, you make almost always come up with a solution for a problem you might have.  The question here is, have you made any attempts to do this?  Are you running into a specific problem in modifying the Gravity Forms logic to do what you want?

Comment: I'm not sure how to even start making these modifications. I tried Googling an answer, but couldn't find one. The closest I could get was not saving any data in the database (a post from May 2012), but I need to kill just one field.

Comment: So you found the spot in the code where the database insert is being made, but were not able to modify the query to not insert data into the field you are concerned about?

Comment: I haven't found anything. I need help start to finish. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to learn Gravity Forms a bit, but one possible way to accomplish this is to use the hook: gform_after_submission. You can add a form ID to the hook name if you are targeting a particular form.

In your function, you can remove the field(s) that you don't want to keep in the database.

For more info on the after submission hook:
http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Gform_after_submission

For info on all hooks available to you:
http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Developer_Docs#Hooks_and_Filters

Comment: You will need the `gform_pre_submission` hook if you want to change the value or hide particular fields before they are stored in the database.